# Should I use method overloading or method overriding when creating converter service

Tags: java, spring, method-overloading, type-conversion, overriding

In a Java Spring API, I'm implementing `GeoJson Conversion Service` to convert different types to geojson, I have `GeoJsonConversionService` interface, and one implementation is `FileGeoJsonConversionServiceImpl` class

First question:
should the service name indicates the "action" or the "actor", which means should it named `ConversionService` or `ConverterService`.

Second:
I found 2 examples of a conversion functionality, one used method overloading which is `Jackson Library`, and the other used method overriding, which is `ResourceHttpMessageConverter`

in Jackson, you have class `ObjectMapper` with different `readTree` methods, based on which type you convert to json, so you had `readTree(InputStream in)` and `readTree(byte[] content)` and so on.

in `MessageConverter` spring class, you have `AbstractHttpMessageConverter` abstract class, implemented by many classes, based on the conversion type also, such as `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` and `StringHttpMessageConverter`, all implementations implements `readInternal` function which is method overriding

so when to use method overloading over overriding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the crux of your question is, when should you use different types of polymorphism in this case:

- Subtype polymorphism (Overriding, Implementing an interface, etc)
- Parametric polymorphism (Overloading)

You would typically use Subtype polymorphism when you want the client code to interact through a consistent interface (the implementation could change but the client doesn't need to). For example I have a `String` that I want to convert to a Java object, but as the client I don't care if its XML or JSON as long as I have a convertor that takes a `String` and gives me the Java object back.

Parametric polymorphism is typically used when the same action could be applied to different types of object for example if I have a JSON document that I need to convert to a Java object, however the JSON object might be a `File`, `String` or `Byte[]` (Byte array), in all cases the input is the JSON, but by overloading the method I don't force the caller to do a conversion first.

Summary:

- Subtype polymorphism - provides a consistent interface, but often provides different behavior.
- Parametric polymorphism - supports many datatypes, but usually provide similar behavior.

Note: These concepts are not mutually exclusive in that I could define an interface with methods that take `File`, `String` or `Byte[]` and then provide implementations for both XML and JSON that implement all three methods.